# foreach loop doesn't work properly

Tags: php

I really don't know what is wrong with this script.. I really thought everything was right, but somehow my strpos syntaxs doesn't work properly or something. The `$_POST['category']` is a select list with multiple selections permitted. So that's why I put it in an array, but maybe it is incorrect?

```
$cat_array = $_POST['category'];

foreach($cat_array as $key => $value )
{
    if(strpos($value, 'n_') !== false)
    {

        // Do something about the new categories.

    } else {

        // work with existing categories

    }

}
```

the html - I also have a jquery that handles the `add category` fields. The `n_(number)-(value)` is created by jquery.

```
<div>
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select name="category" size="10" multiple="MULTIPLE">
  <option class="cat_1" value="1">Cars</option>
  <option class="cat_2" value="2">Lego</option>
  <option class="cat_3" value="3">Country</option>
  <option class="cat_4" value="4">School</option>
  <option class="cat_5" value="5">Cooking</option>
  <option class="cat_6" value="n_6-test">test</option>
  <option class="cat_7" value="n_7-Buuh">Buuh</option>
</select> <br>

<input type="text" name="new_cat" value="" size="40" maxlength="120" placeholder="Category Name"><input class="plus" name="" type="button" value="Add Category">
<p class="plus_comment"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Start debugging: what does `var_dump($cat_array)` output?

Comment: You'd possibly have to use explode() to convert $_POST['category'] to an array. Otherwise I'm assuming $cat_array will be a character-separated string ("a,b,c", etc.).

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($_POST['category'])`?

Comment: Can you also post your error log (if any)

Comment: First: are you sure, $cat_array is really an array()?
What does the corresponding HTML look like?

Comment: @fab the output was this `string(1) "5"` I write the html code for you to see the select list also

Comment: @fragmentedreality you are probably right. It is not even an array yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your category actually an array you have to append brackets to the category like this: `category[]`

So your HTML woul look like this

```
<div>
  <label for="category">Category</label>
  <select name="category[]" size="10" multiple="MULTIPLE">
    <option class="cat_1" value="1">Cars</option>
    <option class="cat_2" value="2">Lego</option>
    <option class="cat_3" value="3">Country</option>
    <option class="cat_4" value="4">School</option>
    <option class="cat_5" value="5">Cooking</option>
    <option class="cat_6" value="n_6-test">test</option>
    <option class="cat_7" value="n_7-Buuh">Buuh</option>
  </select> <br>

  <input type="text" name="new_cat" value="" size="40" maxlength="120" placeholder="Category Name">
  <input class="plus" name="" type="button" value="Add Category">
  <p class="plus_comment"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You know I hate when I make these tiny mistakes.. Of course it was that one.. I didn't even think about preparing my HTML script for the work.. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your `$_POST['category']` is not an array. After seeing your **var_dump** result, it must be a string only. If it as an array, the var_dump should display like this,

```
array (size=1)
  1 => string '5' (length=1)
```

So, check your HTML code whether it passes an array.

EDIT: Change the `category` to `category[]`

Answer (score 1):

try to your select list name

```
category[]
```